# How to use multiple CoreData entities from different viewControllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity

I want to store data into two **CoreData** entities from two `viewControllers`.

I could achieve this, but from a single `viewController`. by using the following code.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let phoneContactRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "PhoneContacts")

        phoneContactRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        let emailContactRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EmailContacts")

        emailContactRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        /*
         // Save to database 

         //object one
         let phoneContactsObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "PhoneContacts", into: context)

            phoneContactsObject.setValue("John", forKey: "name")
        phoneContactsObject.setValue("8335636532", forKey: "number")

         //object two
        let emailContactObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EmailContacts", into: context)
        emailContactObject.setValue("Peter@gmail.com", forKey: "email")
        emailContactObject.setValue("Peter", forKey: "emailname")
         */


        do{

            // Fetch from PhoneContacts entity
            let phoneContactResults = try context.fetch(phoneContactRequest)

            if phoneContactResults.count > 0
            {
                for phoneContactResult in phoneContactResults as! [NSManagedObject]
                {
                    if let phoneContactName = phoneContactResult.value(forKey: "name")
                    {
                        print(phoneContactName)
                    }
                    if let phoneContactNumber = phoneContactResult.value(forKey: "number")
                    {
                        print(phoneContactNumber)
                    }
                }
            }
            // Fetch from EmailContacts entity
            let emailContactResults = try context.fetch(emailContactRequest)

            if emailContactResults.count > 0
            {
                    for emailContactResult in emailContactResults as! [NSManagedObject]
                    {
                        if let emailContactName = emailContactResult.value(forKey: "emailname")
                        {
                            print(emailContactName)
                        }
                        if let emailContactEmail = emailContactResult.value(forKey: "email")
                        {
                            print(emailContactEmail)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        catch
        {            
        }        
    }    
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I have two **CoreData** entities `PhoneContacts` and `EmailContacts`. I could store data into both entities from a single `viewController`. It works.

Now, what I want is, how can I store data into entity1(`PhoneContacts`) from `viewController` 1 and entity2(`EmailContacts`) from `viewController` 2 ?

Should I share `managedObjectContext` to the second viewController?. Or any other better solution is accepted.

I'm using Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to share your MOC? You can share using segues

Comment: `MVC` pattern advocates avoiding creating an independent model interface. You should _never_ have Core Data code within ViewControllers, raki has proposed a good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create and use a singleton class for the CoreData operations.

For example

```
class CoreDataHelper: NSObject
{
   static let sharedInstance = CoreDataHelper()

   func appDelegate()->AppDelegate
   {
     return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   }

   func managedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext
   {
     return self.appDelegate().managedObjectContext
   }
   func fetchPhoneContacts() -> [NSManagedObject]
   {
      // write code to fetch contacts from PhoneContacts entity
   }
   func fetchEmailContacts() -> [NSManagedObject]
   {
      // write code to fetch contacts from EmaliContacts entity
   }
}
```

From viewController1

```
let phoneContatcs = CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance().fetchPhoneContacts()
```

From viewController2

```
let emailContatcs = CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance().fetchEmailContacts()
```

Note: I know the question is for Swift3. But i wrote this answer to give an idea how we can do it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But it reports that value of type 'CoreDataHelper' has no member 'appDelegate'. I tried declaring them into the 'managedObjectContext' method, even though it reports the same. how can i solve this ?

Comment: are you sure that you added '
func appDelegate()->AppDelegate
   {
     return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   }'
 function in your CoreDataHelper ?

Comment: yes its a problem while changing it to swift3. now its ok. but now it reports 'AppDelegate' has no member managedObjectContext. In this line '   return self.appDelegate().managedObjectContext', and this line is present inside managedObjectContext method.

Comment: replace that with self.appDelegate().persistentContainer.viewContext

Comment: The answer i wrote in Swift2 and you are using Swift3 that's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problem using these two entities in two different VC.

All you have to do is, use the following two lines in your another VC:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

And then you can use:

```
let emailContactRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EmailContacts")
emailContactRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

let emailContactObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EmailContacts", into: context)
emailContactObject.setValue("Peter@gmail.com", forKey: "email")
emailContactObject.setValue("Peter", forKey: "emailname")
```

And then, you can save the context & use the same method you are using right now for fetching the second object that you just inserted in DB.

Hope I am making sense.

**EDIT:**

Personally, I would prefer creating core data manager singleton class for simplicity as @raki has suggested.